# Pass a new IResponder to function without making the whole class implement IResponder

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, inline-functions

I've got a custom mxml component that currently implements IResponder.
Passing this IResponder to a function works fine using this.

This, however, includes implementing the public methods result and fault, so I'm asking if it isn't possible to pass a new IResponder to a function, somehow like this:

```
object.function(someProperty:String, new IResponder());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Class you're looking for is Responder.  New Responder(faultFunction, resultFunction);